# How can I delete Minecraft Forge from the Minecraft launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge, minecraft-launcher

On the new Minecraft launcher, I downloaded forge for a mod that I liked. However, the mod was for a later version, so I tried to delete it. The problem is, the delete button doesn't show up. How can I delete that version of forge so I can download the correct version?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to delete forge, or do you want to delete the profile? They're two different things; the profile allows you to launch forge, but deleteing the profile will ultimately leave Forge still on your disk.

---

> I just want to remove the profile.

Usually, to delete a profile, you just select the "..." menu and then hit delete.

[image]

Since that isn't there, you'll have to edit your `launcher_profiles.json` file, located in the `.minecraft` folder and remove the corresponding profile definition.
You might want to rename it to something else so that you can identify it.

[image]

> I want to remove Forge (the install)

Do everything above first that uses the version* you want to delete, then go to your `.minecraft` folder and inside the `/versions` folder, look for your corresponding Forge's folder and delete it.

*Basically, if you want to remove anything forge, obviously remove all profiles that use a Forge version of Minecraft.

[image]

If there is nothing there, you're using an instanced copy of Minecraft (look in its own particular `.minecraft` folder instead), for example, if you are using the Twitch Client, which is `%userprofile%\Twitch\Minecraft\Install` by default.