# How do I delete Forge's profile from the Minecraft launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge, minecraft-launcher

I deleted my old Forge from the versions folder and completely off my Mac, but it's still in my launcher and I can't delete it. It's not even an option and I have no idea why. Unfortunately, I can't download the new Forge until this is gone. Anyone know how to delete it?

Comment: There should normally be a delete button. Maybe your launcher window is too small to see it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete Minecraft Forge?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/353742/how-can-i-delete-minecraft-forge)

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the launcher profile automatically created by Forge upon installation isn't being deleted yet, and it can't be deleted in the launcher.

First, open your `launcher_profiles.json` file in the `.minecraft` folder. Search down to a line which is like `"forge": {`, and delete all the thing in the hashtag (including `"forge": {` and `}`), an example might be deleting this:

```
"forge" : {
      "created" : "2019-07-20T01:06:51.483Z",
      "icon" : "Furnace",
      "lastUsed" : "2019-07-28T00:46:12.415Z",
      "lastVersionId" : "1.8.9-forge1.8.9-11.15.1.2318-1.8.9",
      "name" : "forge",
      "type" : "custom"
}
```

If your launcher is still open at this time, try to restart it, and you should see the forge profile gone.